# Is there an algorithms that calculates the highest number calculable by an array of numbers?

Tags: algorithms

I was planning on creating a Code Golf question, but I would like to check first if there is an available 'algorithm'. This is my first question on Mathematics. Not sure this is the right place to ask.

I was wondering if there is a system which calculates the highest number available by an array of numbers with some basic operators.

**Rules**

- You have to start with 1 and continue rising by one
- In every calculation you can use every number just once
- To start off 'simple', you can only use the basic operators +, -, × and /
- The input could be of any length (amount of numbers), and all numbers
- You cannot skip one. If you can't get the next number, the 'game' is over

**Hold on, an example**

For this example the input numbers are: 2, 3 and 6. Now we just check from 1 to infinite if the number is calculable by the numbers in the array.

1 = 3 - 2
2 = 2
3 = 3
4 = 6 - 2
5 = 2 + 3
6 = 6
7 = 6 + 3 - 2
8 = 6 + 2
**9 = 6 × 3 / 2**
10 = ???
11 = ???
12 = 6 × 2

**Result**

In this example this result would be 9.

Comment: Could you give a reference explaining what "Code Golf" is ?

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: I don't understand the example. Why $2\times 3\times 6=36$ is not valid?

Comment: Because of the rule "You cannot skip one. If you can't get the next number, the 'game' is over". Because else you could just multiply the numbers always. See the example. 12 Isn't valid.

Comment: Yes, there is an algorithm. There are only finitely many expressions buildable from the inout after all.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. I'm interested what this will do if you pick random numbers between ranges. The lower the input numbers, the easier to make a calculation, but you can't get really large numbers. Is there never done any research on this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, not sure how good is this algorithm, but check it once!

1. Take all possible subsets (sublists) of the given set (list) of numbers.
2. Perform all possible operations with all possible combinations and store the result in a set (list).
3. Now, sort the set (list) in ascending order.
4. Wherever you find a number missing in the ascending order, that is the highest number you can achieve.

**Note**: While coding, this is going to be a long code. Since it involves a lot of operations you would be doing on your data, I would recommend you using different functions for different operations. For example, write functions for having combinations, operations of +, - , *, / and then have functions for operations in different combinations and so on.

Also, I am pretty sure this algorithm is really really complex, i.e., its time complexity is too high! But, this was the first vague thought I had after looking at this question. I hope this helps.

Any suggestions or edits are welcome!